# How to load images for training a neural network in real time in Keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, computer-vision

I'm using `Keras` with `tensorflow` backend. I have a large dataset (Caltech 256) that I want to train.

I've created four `.npy` files called `training`, `trainlbl`, `testing`, `testlbl`.

Now instead of running `np.load()` which almost completely occupies my ram, how can I load them from disk in real time while training itself?
From searching on the internet I get an idea that it can be done through Keras's data generator, but I'm not able to understand how.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it would be possible to answer your question in this post, but i think it isn't useful because you need more knowledge how to use or write deep learning networks.

My suggestion would be to use existing tutorials which shows you how to create neural networks for image classification.
A very nice example is this blog post: https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2017/12/11/image-classification-with-keras-and-deep-learning/

This guy shows you how you use DataGenerator from Keras.
DataGenerator can do many more things than just lazy loading images from disk.